# Winforms and datagridview reload

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridview inside a winform. I need to reload with a button the second datagridview 2 when I change the data inside the datagridview1.

datagriview1 modified ---> click button update ---> reload datagridview 2.
it's not working I don't know why.

```
     using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.IO;

        namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataSet dv = new DataSet();
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    FileStream stream = new FileStream("file.xml",FileMode.Open);
                    ds.ReadXml(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    FileStream stream1 = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);
                    dv.ReadXml(stream1);
                    stream1.Close();
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = dv.Tables[0];

                    //DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;


                }

                private void updateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    ds.WriteXml("file.xml");
                    //reload the datagridview 2 after modification intot the datagridview1
dv.reset();                    
FileStream stream1 = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);

                    dv.ReadXml(stream1);
                    stream1.Close();
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = dv.Tables[0];
dataGridView2.ResetBindings();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `ResetBindings` function on `DataGrid` that should do what  you want.

`dataGridView2.ResetBindings();`

Comment: It's there ... and has been there since the beginning. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings.aspx

Comment: dv.Tables[0] is not what you want. You want to reset the bindings on the grid view itself

Comment: I tried under visual studio 2010 and I don't find the ResetBindings().

Comment: I tried this but don't work :ds.WriteXml("file.xml");
            //reload the datagridview 2 after modification intot the datagridview1

            dataGridView2.ResetBindings();
                          
            
            //
            FileStream stream1 = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);
            dv.ReadXml(stream1);
            stream1.Close();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dv.Tables[0];

Comment: I tried this didn't work ;/     ds.WriteXml("file.xml");
                   
            FileStream stream1 = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);
            dv.ReadXml(stream1);
            stream1.Close();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dv.Tables[0];
            dataGridView2.ResetBindings();

Comment: Thank you very much I found too, I need to reset the dataset too.  ds.WriteXml("file.xml");
            dv.Reset();     
            FileStream stream1 = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);
            dv.ReadXml(stream1);
            stream1.Close();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dv.Tables[0];
            dataGridView2.ResetBindings();